# How to use pyFFTW class to do a 2 d fourier transformation?

Tags: python, fft, fftw, pyfftw

I want to use pyFFTW to create a 2d fft and ifft. However, the documentations were a bit confusing:
https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/tutorial.html#the-workhorse-pyfftw-fftw-class

So, essentially, the code:

```
a = pyfftw.empty_aligned(128, dtype='complex128')
b = pyfftw.empty_aligned(128, dtype='complex128')

fft_object = pyfftw.FFTW(a, b)
```

I didn't understand what is a fft_object, and why it needs a and b as input, or even what is a and b doing here. Are they just some empty templet to simulate data of input and output? what's the function of this process?

```
import numpy

# Generate some data
ar, ai = numpy.random.randn(2, 128)
a[:] = ar + 1j*ai

fft_a = fft_object()
```

I also didn't understand in which way a was transformed into fft_a, there was not even function call. How did the function knew that a was the input? (I read the whole page and found a mention in the pyfftw.builders

```
fft_object = pyfftw.builders.fft(a)
```

Still, what is fft_object defined by pyfftw.builders.fft(a)? and what were builders doing?)

Also, if fft was

```
pyfftw.FFTW(a, b, axes=(0,1))
```

would the ifft be

```
pyfftw.FFTW(a, b, direction='FFTW_BACKWARD', axes=(0,1))#or
pyfftw.FFTW(a, b, direction='FFTW_BACKWARD', axes=(1,0))#or
pyfftw.FFTW(b, a, direction='FFTW_BACKWARD', axes=(0,1))#or
pyfftw.FFTW(b, a, direction='FFTW_BACKWARD', axes=(1,0))
```

?

Suppose I have a 3 by 3 matrix x=np.ones([3,3]);

How can I do a fft2(x) and ifft2(x)?

Further, how can I do a rfft2(x) and irfft2(x)?(rfft2 and irfft2 represent fast fourier transformation in real domain).

Comment: Best thing to do to understand what the `fft_object` is is to read the [API docs](https://pyfftw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/source/pyfftw/pyfftw.html#fftw-class).

Comment: To answer one of your specific questions, `a` and `b` are the input and output arrays respectively. That is, they become the internal arrays that store the input and the output. There are various ways to interact with them through the `FFTW` api.

Comment: To answer your final q: If `b` is the output of your FFT (the second arg), then `b` should be the input to the inverse FFT (assuming that's what you're trying to do!). If you set `a` to be the output, then you'll overwrite the input to your FFT when you run it. You almost certainly don't want `a` to be the input to your inverse FFT. The axes order doesn't matter.